# Can't parse an rss link even though I have installed and imported the BeautifulSoup module

Tags: python, parsing, rss

I keep generating an error every time

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

req=urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.cnn.com/politics?rss=1')
xml=BeautifulSoup(req,'xml')

for item in xml.findAll('link'):
    print(item)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/Pentazoid/Desktop/Become a professional python programmer/Section 2 web python programming/parsing_xml-46.py", line 1, in <module>
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named 'bs4'
```

I have installed >pip install beautifulsoup4 in windows command prompt but I am still generating an error

Comment: maybe you had some error message during installation. Or you have installed two Pythons and you install BS in one version but you run code with another.

Comment: Where is the bs4 folder supposed to be

Comment: C:\Windows.old\Users\Pentazoid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\bs4

Comment: every version has own folder for modules. If you have two versions of Python then `pip` can install for one version but `python.exe` can run different version. You can try `python.exe -m pip install beautifulsoup4`. BTW: On Linux I have installed Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5 and I have programs `pip2`, `pip3.4`, `pip3.5` to install modules in different version.

Comment: And then when I run "python.exe -m pip install beautifulsoup4" in command prompt, my program will run properly

Comment: Here is the output of the program when I try to execute it in command prompt:

"Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Pentazoid>python.exe -m pip install beautifulsoup4
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): beautifulsoup4 in c:\users\pentazoid\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\Users\Pentazoid>
"

Comment: do you use this `pyhton.exe` to run your code -  `python.exe script.py` ?